# Socket server best approach

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

So I've been writing a chat program/server in Java. 
So far I have a pretty nice client, and a what seems like effective server.

Basically the server listens on two sockets, one for everything chat related, and one to distribute updates when needed

When a client connects it checks the version against the server, if needed it connects to the file socket and downloads the updated files.

Well anyways what I'm trying to figure out is what the best server approach is,  for example right now when a client connects it opens a new thread (runnable class) and keeps listening while the thread handles logging in, sending and receiving data and pings.

When a client sends a message to the server, the server cycles through all connected clients sending them the message.

This seems to me like if 1000+ clients were connected it would cause a lot of stability, memory, cpu and lag issues, so I'm curious what the best way of handling 1000's of connections would be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that could be interesting in ckeck the [Netty Project](http://netty.io/). It is a framework to develop client-server applications. From their website:

> Netty is a NIO client server framework which enables quick and easy
>   development of network applications such as protocol servers and
>   clients. It greatly simplifies and streamlines network programming
>   such as TCP and UDP socket server.

This framework [is used for Twitter](https://blog.twitter.com/2013/netty-4-at-twitter-reduced-gc-overhead) for example, because is

- Better throughput, lower latency
- Less resource consumption
- Minimized unnecessary memory copy

Comment: your answer is reasonable :)

Comment: it helped me and we have created a chat application as our final year project even we have submitted our project and we got top marks but still I am going to implement Netty I believe it will make its performance very high, Thanks man :)

Comment: This seems like the best production ready library, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Opening a thread for each client is not viable for a scaling environment. You should use something asynchronous, to limit the number of threads.

One option would be one thread for receiving/sending, and one for handling connections. However again, this won`t scale well.

You should look into how Java handles **asynchronous** (i.e. non-blocking) sockets, here is a tutorial that seems pretty nice.

http://zguide.zeromq.org/java:asyncsrv

Also, using just the core Java SE7

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.html

For other operations, you could set up a threadpool for managing everything efficiently while keeping up to the scale of the connected users, but that's again a design choice that depends massively on the type of application you're creating.